# Microsoft Word Add-In Default Icon in Ribbon

Tags: ms-word, word-addins

I'm trying to get a Word add-in published into the Microsoft App Store and continue to get rejected for '1100.5.6.2 Default Icon in Ribbon' 'The Ribbon icon for the offer is displaying a default icon in Microsoft 365 on Windows,  Word (16.0.13426.20330) 64-bit.'. I've included a IconUrl with a DefaultValue in the manifest file, along with every sized Icons defined under OfficeTab, but it's still not loading the icon when being reviewed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed this procedure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/iconurl

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just got back the same response but just realised one of my urls was returning a 404...